# jquery find the index of a selected element

Tags: jquery

hello I want to retrieve the index of the column of a selected item in a table to use to do a color indicator in the header of the table, when the mouse moves, the head of the table containing the element changes color

this is my function that i creat

```
$(function () {

    var content = $('tr').children().children().children();
    content.hover(function () {
        var col2 = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
        var index2 = col2.index($(this));

        $('tr:first-child :nth-child(' + index2 + ')').css('background-color', 'red')

    });
});
```

thanks

Comment: Be aware index() is zero based while :nth-child() first index is 1

Comment: paste html example you are using

Comment: It works like `parent_collection.index(current_element_child)` (or reversed), and you can't find the index of an element in a random collection, your element is not part of the collection you're checking for the elements index in.

Comment: this is not the only mistak,i think, the function that i did do not return any number or it return string ????

Comment: @user3506058 Providing a jsFiddle would help you to get fast answer otherwise it's quite hard without seeing any HTML markup to figure out what you are trying to do... And this is awful `.children().children().children()` just as `.parent().parent().parent()`

Answer (score 1):

`index` only works if the argument is a child of the element you invoke it on. In your case `$(this)` is a great-grandchild of `col2`. I think you need to use:

```
var index2 = col2.index($(this).parent().parent());
```

Then you need to add 1 to `index2` when you use it with `:nth-child`, because that selector is  1-based.

```
    $('tr:first-child :nth-child(' + (index2+1) + ')').css('background-color', 'red')
```

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
<h:form id="form">
<p:growl id="messaget"></p:growl>
<center>
<p:panelGrid  columns="#{horaireBean.listCalendrier.size()+1}"
styleClass="horaire1"  >
<p:outputLabel >
<center>
<h4>Catégorie/Calendrier</h4>
</center>
</p:outputLabel>

<c:forEach var="cal" begin="1"
end="#{horaireBean.listCalendrier.size()}">

<p:outputLabel 
value="#{horaireBean.listCalendrier.get(cal-1).designation}" />

</c:forEach>

<c:forEach var="j" begin="1"
end="#{horaireBean.listCategorie.size()}">
<p:outputLabel
value="#{horaireBean.listCategorie.get(j-1).desigCat}" />
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1"
end="#{horaireBean.listCalendrier.size()}">


<p:selectOneMenu  value="#{horaireBean.sequence2}" styleClass="horaire2"   
converter="sequenceConverter" >
<f:selectItem itemLabel="#{horaireBean.listehoraire.get(j-1).get(i-1).desigSeq}"/>
<f:selectItems value="#{sequencebean.listeSequence}" var="seq" itemLabel="#    
{seq.desigSeq}" itemValue="#{seq}"  />
<p:ajax  event="change"  process="@this" onstart="#{horaireBean.attribuer(j-1,i-1)}"  
update=":formheader:enregistrer :formheader:annuler"  />
</p:selectOneMenu>   
</c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
</p:panelGrid>          
</center>
</h:form>`
```

Comment: thank you this is my xhtml page, i creat a dynamic tabele that contain a selectone menu in each cell